# How to remove a product from cart using module?

Tags: magento2, module

How to remove/disable an item from the cart using a module? 
I want to remove an item from the cart from my module with some conditions.

Comment: which type of condition ?

Comment: i am using a module to update custom price to products, so of the product price is < 100 then i have to disable the item from the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event observer for your requirements.

> etc/event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="layout_load_before_abc" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\RemoveProduct" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Observer/RemoveProduct.php

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class RemoveProduct implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $itemModel;
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $itemModel,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->itemModel = $itemModel;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $checkoutSession = $this->getCheckoutSession();
        $allItems = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();//returns all teh items in session
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();//item id of particular item
            $quoteItem = $this->getItemModel()->load($itemId);//load particular item which you want to delete by his item id
            if ("Your Condition") {
                $quoteItem->delete();//deletes the item
            }
        }
    }

    public function getCheckoutSession(){
        $checkoutSession = $this->checkoutSession; //checkout session
        return $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function getItemModel(){
        $itemModel = $this->itemModel; //Quote item model to load quote item
        return $itemModel;
    }   
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: can you explain, where i have to create files and where should i define it all?

Comment: You can use it in your controller, helper or in block class as per your requirements.

Comment: No, i just want to remove it when the page loads. i am not using any controller my own.

Comment: Ok, so you can use event observer for the same. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Properly Explained and Clear Answer.

Comment: Hello, i tried this, but i am getting the wrong produt ID from $itemId = $item->getItemId();

Comment: Item id is different from the product id it comes from the quote table, you can check the data coming in the $item with $item->getData()